# Error when adding working query to the "Views"

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I am using SQL Server 2019 and if I use new query and add code below, I am getting a positive outcome, however, if I use the same code to create a view, I am getting this error

> Error Source:.Net SqlClient Data Provider Error Message: The CONCAT function requires 2 arguments(s). Incorrect syntax near the keyword "AS"

[image]

I know it has to do with concatenation with Date and Notes but why would it happen on "view" and not the "query" and any idea on how to make it work?

I actually need to use a view in this case.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    (SELECT string_agg(Controller, ', ') AS Expr1
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT co.Controller
          FROM dbo.Controller AS co 
          INNER JOIN dbo.ChipsetController AS ac1 ON ac1.ControllerID = co.ID
          WHERE (ac1.ID = ac.ID)) AS x) AS vController,
    (SELECT string_agg(Chipset, ', ') AS Expr1
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT cs.Chipset
          FROM dbo.Chipset AS cs 
          INNER JOIN dbo.ChipsetController AS ac2 ON ac2.ControllerID = cs.ControllerID AND ac2.ChipsetID = cs.ID
          WHERE (ac2.ID = ac.ID)) AS y) AS vChipset,
    (SELECT string_agg(concat(Date, ': ',Notes), '  ') AS Expr1
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT nd.Notes, nd.Date
          FROM dbo.NotesChipset AS nd 
          INNER JOIN dbo.ChipsetController AS ac4 ON ac4.ControllerID = nd.ControllerID AND ac4.ChipsetID = nd.ChipsetID
          WHERE (ac4.ID = ac.ID)) AS z_1) AS vNotes
FROM 
    dbo.ChipsetController AS ac
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

Comment: I'm having trouble telling where each subquery ends and which is inside which. Is it possible to format your code, e.g. use indentation to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: @downernn: I was just going to say the same thing - **proper indentation** and formatting can go a **looooooong way** to make it a lot easier to understand a query....

Comment: **Don't use the visual designer** Second question today where this has caused problems with the `CONCAT` function. Just execute `CREATE VIEW dbo.Whatever AS SELECT ...` in a new query window

Comment: @MartinSmith... Thank you for the link. That helped and fixed my issue :-)